# Eclipse commandline argument with angle bracket

Tags: java, eclipse, arguments

So I have BinarySearch class from [here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/11model/BinarySearch.java.html) I am trying to run this in eclipse. I added the argument as `tinyW.txt < tinyT.txt` in Run > Run Configuration > Arguments > Program Argument. But it doesn't give me the expected output, instead it waits for an input for me in the eclipse's console.

Any idea how it can be done right off eclipse?

The program depends on [this](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/stdlib/stdlib.jar) archive.

Comment: What's the expectation? Did you want to redirect `stdin` to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your main method:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        // read in the integers from a file
        In in = new In(args[0]);
        int[] whitelist = in.readAllInts();

        // more.....
```

your `In` class is instantiated using this method (look at [this](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/12oop/In.java.html))

```
public In(String s) {
   try {
       // first try to read file from local file system
       File file = new File(s);
       if (file.exists()) {

       // more....
```

this means that your first argument is the actual filename that is passed to get data from. Since your arguments array is `["tinyW.txt", "<", "tinyT.txt"]` you are passing `tinyW.txt` as argument and ignoring the rest.

**Option 1**
All said and done, and supposing that `tinyW.txt` is the inputfile, just remove `<` and `tinyT.txt` from your Eclipse configuration and keep the filename.

Then, in  go to `Run` menu and choose `Debug Configurations` -> `Common` and in `Standard Input and Output` section you can choose `File` and put a path to create a file for the output.

**Option 2** 
Remove only the `<` from the parameter list and modify the `BinarySearch` class. Instead of doing output to standard output, you can use the second parameter as a path where create a new file and write the output in that file.

Comment: thanks @giampaolo. I had been using terminal for this, but this is definitely convenient.